# Configurable SMTP account in Codeigniter app

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, passwords

I'd like to let the user edit the email account that will be sending notifications on a CodeIgniter web app.  I usually use something like:

```
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
        'smtp_pass' => 'xxx', // hardcoded unhashed password
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'utf8'
    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

But that is hardcoded and won't let the user configure or edit on admin's options.  I was thinking on calling this from the database but then the email password will be exposed (not hashed) in the table, right?

Is there another way to make it **configurable** and **secure**?

Comment: So use `'smtp_user' => $this->post['post_field_here']`, or store it in the database, and retrieve it later.

Comment: Thank you @FrankerZ.  My first idea was to store it on the database but I'm worried about the fact that it will have to be stored unhashed, right? I rather not have plain passwords on a database.

Comment: No matter what, you'll need to pass the password to `smpt.googlemail.com`. You can use the codeigniter encryption/decryption class for more security: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html

Comment: storing it in os environment variables are more secure than storing it in the db but won't be configurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to pass the raw password via SMTP, a hashed password will not work. You will need to use 2-way encryption. You can use the codeigniter encryption/decryption class for more security: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html

Should be as simple as:

```
$plain_text = 'This is a plain-text message!';
$ciphertext = $this->encryption->encrypt($plain_text);

// Outputs: This is a plain-text message!
echo $this->encryption->decrypt($ciphertext);
```

Additionally, asking for GMAIL passwords is rather insecure. I'd look to using an OAUTH approach, to have users approve your application: https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools

Comment: Double accepted because 1. Encryption will help a little on regular SMTP password storage 2. I only used gmail as an exaple but now I'll also add an option for OAUTH if the user will use gmail or gSuite account. Thank you @FrankerZ